# Create polygon with a certain radius

Tags: php, mysql

i have a polygon with some radius. Something like [**this**](http://www.mathopenref.com/polygonradius.html). Now i need to

- insert it into mysql database.
- find whether a point lies inside or outside of the polygon. (Does it include getting the vertices of it?)

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What does this have to do with php or mysql?

Comment: The polygon data must be stored in mysql database and the same should be retrieved using php, to get the vertices and find whether a point lies inside it. I added more details to my question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: is polygon regular or irregular one and no of vertices (i.e. constant or variable)?

Comment: seems more mathematical question to me than programming related, but could you add a bit description. (at least you need some predefined parameter like (the center, no of vertices, and raduis)) .. i cannot answer at once. i could add concepts and update bit by bit everyday.

Comment: polygon would be a regular one and iam not sure about the number of vertices... i may not know it, but can assume it fixed as 4 or 5.

Comment: more vertices, more trouble, and also you need to know the orientation of the polygon beforehand checking for checking the point of the polygon

Comment: are you online, if please come to php chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding, if the point lies inside the polygon or not, that will be done in update

```
//this assumes that the orientation of your polygon is
//http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pentagon.svg

$pass=1;

function filter($init, $final, $center)
{

    if(($final['a']['x']-$init['x'])*($center['y']-$init['y'])-($final['a']['y'] - $init['y'])*($center['x']-$init['x']) > 0)
        return $final['a'];
    else
        return $final['b']; 
}


function getNextPoint($init, $center, $distance, $slope)
{
    global $pass;

    $final['a']['x'] = $init['x']+$distance/sqrt(1+tan($slope)*tan($slope));
    $final['a']['y'] = $init['y']+(tan($slope)*$distance)/sqrt(1+tan($slope)*tan($slope));

    $final['b']['x'] = $init['x']-$distance/sqrt(1+tan($slope)*tan($slope));
    $final['b']['y'] = $init['y']-(tan($slope)*$distance)/sqrt(1+tan($slope)*tan($slope));


    echo "<br/><br/>";  
    echo "Pass: $pass <br/>";
    echo "Slope: ".$slope."<br/>";  


    if($pass == 1){ 
        $point = $final['b'];
        $distance = $distance*2*sin(pi()/5);
        $slope = 0;
    }
    else{   
        $point = filter($init, $final, $center);
        $slope = $slope+pi()/2.5;
    }       
    echo "Position: ";
    print_r($point);
    echo "<br/>";

    echo "Distance : ".distance($init['x'], $init['y'], $point['x'], $point['y']);


    if($pass == 7){ 
        return $point;  
    }
    else{
        //echo "x: ".($point['x'])." y: ".($point['y'])." <br/>";
        $pass++;

        getNextPoint($point, $center, $distance, $slope);
    }

    //echo "x: ".($point['x'])." y: ".($point['y'])." <br/>";
}

function polygon($vertices=5, $centerX=10, $centerY=10, $radius=5)
{

    $internalangle = ($vertices-2)*pi()/$vertices;

    $slope = pi()+($internalangle)/2;

    $init['x'] = 10;
    $init['y'] = 10;

    getNextPoint($init, $init, 5, $slope);
}



polygon();

/*
function getx($slope, $x1, $y1, $y)
{
    return (($y-$y1)/$slope+$x1);
}

function gety($slope, $x1, $y1, $x)
{
    return ($slope*($x-$x1)+$y1);
}

*/

function distance($initx, $inity, $finalx, $finaly)
{

    return sqrt(($initx-$finalx)*($initx-$finalx)+($inity-$finaly)*($inity-$finaly));

}

function getslope($final, $init)
{
    return atan(($final['y']-$init['y'])/($final['x']-$init['x']))*180/pi();
}
```

Comment: This seems to work well with a regular polygon of 5 vertices (a pentagon). Haven't tried yet with 4 or 6 vertices though.

Answer (score 2):

Classifying points requires that the polygon be fully defined. Normally you will need either the vertices in order around the polygon, or else some constraints that fully define the polygon (for example: regular, centered at the origin, with one vertex on the +x axis, and a given number of sides). If the polygon is self-intersecting, you will also need to define what "inside" and "outside" mean in that case (there are several, non-equivalent definitions).

**EDIT:** If you google "php polygon" you'll find lots of code for point-in-polygon testing ([here](http://www.assemblysys.com/dataServices/php_pointinpolygon.php), for example, although I don't vouch for the correctness of that code).

Comment: Thanks, but i want to know how can i find a point in polygon if i know only the radius of polygon. The polygon is centered at the origin.

Comment: Even if the polygon is centered at the origin and is a regular polygon (all sides and angles equal), that's not enough. Consider a square of radius 1. If the diagonals are aligned with the X and Y axes, then the point (.75, 0) is inside the square; if the diagonals are at 45 degrees, then it is not.

Comment: ok, it sounds that i need to have the polygon points for finding whether a point is inside a polygon. Can i atleast find the vertices, if i have the radius of a polygon?

Comment: @dskanth - NO! You need to know how the polygon is rotated around the origin. Think about the example of a square again.

Comment: The polygon is rotated anticlockwise around the origin. For example, I have a center of origin (10,10), radius of polygon as 5, and there are 5 sides (vertices) for polygon.

Comment: @dskanth - everything that you have given so far does not define the polygon. In particular, "rotated anticlockwise" does not specify the rotation. Is there a vertex at (15,10)? At (10,15)? At (5,10)? At (10,5)? (You can have at most one of those cases, and perhaps none, with a **regular** pentagon. And you don't say that it is regular.) Unless the polygon is **fully** defined, it is impossible to decide which points are in or out. (There are partial solutions--for instance, the largest inscribed circle is always in for a regular polygon, and that is known without specifying the rotation.)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Ted. So what all i need to find the vertices of a polygon, besides the radius? Any example is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function point_in_reg_poly($sides, $radius, $p_x, $p_y) {
    $centerAngle = 2*pi() / $sides;
    $internalRadius = $radius * sin($centerAngle / 2);

    $angle = atan2($p_x, $p_y);
    $length = sqrt($p_x*$p_x + $p_y*$p_y);

    if($length > $radius)
        return false;

    //normalize angle to angle from center of nearest segment
    $angle = fmod($angle + 2*pi(), $centerAngle) - $centerAngle/2;

    return $internalRadius > $length * cos($angle);
} ?>
```

This one works. But really, couldn't you have spotted the syntax errors!

Comment: Sorry but i got a null value when i tried with: **echo point_in_reg_poly(4, 5, 10, 10);**

Comment: Its been a while since I coded in PHP. It's possible the modulo `%` operator isn't valid for floating point numbers. Most likely though, PI isn't a defined constant. Treat that as php-esque pseudocode